# I am making request on api but it is coming authorisation failed. How to include authorisation token in the fetch link

Tags: reactjs, api, https, react-router

I have this question regarding http resquest using fetch command in react.js, response is coming that authorization failed. I am new to all this stuff. How to successfully fetch data from the link ?

I tried this code:

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from "react";
import { async } from "q";


function Shop(){
  useEffect(() => { //this function will run when component did mount
    fetchItems();
  },[]);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/upcoming/get");
    console.log(data)
    const items = await data.json();
    console.log(items);
    setItems(items);
  }


return(<div>
  { items.map(item => (
   <h1 key={item.itemid}>{item.name}</h1>
   ))
  }           
  </div>
  )
}
export default Shop;
```

I am getting following error while fetching data:

**Error: {"success":false,"error":"Please add your Authorization token.","eCode":"authorization.empty","_console":"https://console.fortniteapi.com"}**

Comment: Check documentation for fortnite api, there would be private key required for authentication and try to get result using Postman before using react.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add it in headers, like that:

```
fetch(
    "https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/upcoming/get",
    {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer [your-token-here]'
        },
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated the code accordingly. Now I am getting error : "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403"

Comment: Are you adding correct token? The error means your token is invalid and you are not authorized to access.

Comment: ok, I got the answer, it was the fault of the link. It is instead-       "https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/upcoming/get",

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this helped me a lot - Appreciated

Thanks